# Undefined constant http/2

Tags: php, curl, push-notification

I am trying to work out how to send push notifications to apple iOS devices from a php site. I had a php script that was working before the new http/2 way but since they do not support it anymore, it of course does not work.

The new script I have is this:

```
<?php


    $ch = curl_init();
    $device_token   = 'correctDevice';
    $pem_file       = 'correctPemfile';
    $pem_secret     = 'correctCode';
    $apns_topic     = 'correctAppID';

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("apns-topic: $apns_topic"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $pem_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $pem_secret);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE , true);

    echo "Try 1 ================================================" . PHP_EOL;

    //setup and send first push message
    $url = "https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/$device_token";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "{$url}");
    $sample_alert = '{"aps":{"alert":"hi #1","sound":"default"}}';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sample_alert);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch);
    //var_dump($response);
    //var_dump($httpcode);

    echo "Try 2 ================================================" . PHP_EOL;

    //setup and send second push message
    $url = "https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/$device_token";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "{$url}");
    $sample_alert = '{"aps":{"alert":"hi #2","sound":"default"}}';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sample_alert);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch);
    //var_dump($response);
    //var_dump($httpcode);

    curl_close($ch);
    

?>
```

I've blocked out the device token, pem file, secret and app ID of course, but they are all correct.

The issue with it is that I get this error:
`Warning: Use of undefined constant CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0 - assumed 'CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)`

What could this issue be? I tried echoing `phpinfo()` and see if it supports http/2 and I found this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php):

> CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0 (int)
> Available since cURL 7.33.0

Check the cURL version (e.g. by using `phpinfo()`).

Comment: It says: cURL Information 7.29.0 which must be why the error is there. How do I update it to 7.33?

Comment: It depends what kind of access/permissions you have on the server in question. It spans from asking hosting support to do it yourself (e.g. like this https://serverfault.com/questions/321321/upgrade-curl-to-latest-on-centos).